Unable to join EC2 worker to VirtualBox master
Im deploying a Hybrid Cloud(VirtualBox-AWS) Kubernetes cluster. What I have done so far:

Set the control-plane on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS via VirtualBox 6.1.
Change network adapter to bridged
Ran the kubeadm init (succeeded with no issues)
Went to AWS and launched 2 t2.micro instances
On each instance Ive installed all the necessary kubetools
Checked that I can do SSH between the master and EC2 and vice direction - success
Checked ping from master to EC2 - success
Added port 6443 inbound/outbound rules for both of the instances security groups
In the master node Ive checked the cluster status:


But when Im trying to join the worker instance to the cluster Im always getting the error:
[discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get "https://MY_VM_BRIDGED_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I also have checked on the master:

Ive noticed that the namespaces during the operations are different, which prompted me to question whether this might be related to a VPC/subnet issue?
Do you think there is a solution for this one?
Thank you for your assistance.
